Azure Serverfarm AutoScale Settings Scale In Isn't Triggering
I have a P1V2 SKU server farm in Azure, and I've added some rules based on memory percentage and CPU percentage to the autoscale setting:
Scale out: (one of the rules need to be true)
Memory percentage (Avg) > 80%
CPU percentage (Avg) > 60%
Increase count by: 1
Duration: 10 minutes
Scale in: (both rules needed to be true)
Memory percentage (Avg) < 30%
CPU percentage (Avg) < 20%
Decrease count by: 1
Duration: 10 minutes
Enable metric divide by instance count: Yes for all
In terms of CPU percentage, it rarely spikes at all, it stays below 10%. Our mover is memory percentage.
The scale out rule is working well, if I'm at 1 instance and I get to an average memory % of 90 let's say over the last 10 minutes, it will execute the scale out, now I'm at 2 instances.
By my understanding, this means per instance, I'm at 45%. All is well.
Then the load lightens later on, per instance memory percentage goes to 25%. To my understanding, we're ready for a scale in based on the scale in rule I've defined.
To my understanding, autoscale performs a calculation to check if flapping will occur, going from 2 to 1 instance:
25% * 2 (instances) / 1 (instance) = 50% memory percentage 

According to the above, the resultant single instance will have a per instance memory percentage of 50%, so it should not subsequently trigger the scale out rule ( > 60%) after scaling in (flapping).
However, I'm still getting flapping warnings all the time, my serverfarm will not autoscale in. Need some help diagnosing the issue from an Azure autoscale expert.

you have set the scale-out threshold to 80% CPU and 60% memory, and the scale-in threshold to 20% CPU and 30% memory. However, the CPU usage rarely spikes above 10%, so the scale-in rule is not being triggered. The issue could be that the scale-in rule is too strict and needs to be adjusted. Also check if the autoscale engine is processing only one profile at a time and if the key metrics are kept out of the default profile. Within a profile, there can be multiple rules. On scale-out, autoscale runs if any rule is met. On scale-in, autoscale requires all rules to be met.

Here are few MS docs for your reference-   Autoscaling - Use Azure Monitor autoscale

Flapping in Autoscale - Scaling by more than one instance-   Get started with autoscale in Azure - Create your first autoscale setting


I hope your issue is already resolved. Here are my 2 cents

As per Microsoft's documenation on Auto scalling
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-best-practices#autoscale-best-practices
Difference between scale-out condition and scale-in condition is WIDE enough , ideal count is 40%
Remove Divide by instance count.
SCALE-OUT should happen quickly ( for ex 5 minutes ) and SCALE-IN should be slower than SCALE-OUT ( 10 minutes ), as per this rule you can change your time period
FLAPPING while Scale-in will incur cost because your instances could not scale-in within time. But if this error is coming while scaling from 2 to 1 , you can ignore this error.
I hope your are either using AVG or MAX aggregation while SCALE-OUT and SCALE-IN and NOT the mix of both


I've made the duration for Scale-in 30 minutes (Scale-out is 10 minutes). I have removed "Divide by instance count" for scale-out, but I cannot remove it for Scale-in as the rule will never trigger (Memory < 35), unless it is enabled. Why can I ignore flapping from 2 to 1?
